# What is the difference between OptionalAttribute and optional parameters in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, attributes, optional-parameters

I'm researching someone else's code and there is a method like this:

```
public SomeClass DoSomething(string param1, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue("")] string optional)
```

Why would someone use these attributes instead of

```
public SomeClass DoSomething(string param1, string optional = "")
```

Is there any difference in the behavior, etc.?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.defaultparametervalueattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If they weren't using C# 4, for example? I believe the second version will compile into exactly the first version...

(I've compiled them both and run them through ILDASM - there were no significant differences.)

Comment: unrelated: is this some high profile user magic? You added the last sentence later, and still I do not see the edit history :)

Comment: @Sunny: There's a five minute grace period, during which edits by the author aren't shown.