# Trying to use optional parameters in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

But I am receiving the error

> Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters

Though my optional parameter is appearing after my required parameter? What am I doing wrong here?

```
public string UserAnswer(string optInput = null, [Optional] int num1)
{
        bool isOperatorValid;

        do
        {
            string answer = optInput ?? Console.ReadLine();
            isOperatorValid = true;

            switch (answer)
            {
                case "a":
                    Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} + {num2} = " + (num1 + num2));
                    break;

                case "s":
                    Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} - {num2} = " + (num1 - num2));
                    break;

                case "m":
                    Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} * {num2} = " + (num1 * num2));
                    break;

                case "d":
                    Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} / {num2} = " + (num1 / num2));
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input please try again");
                    isOperatorValid = false;
                    break;
            };
        } while (!isOperatorValid);

        return optInput;
}
```

Comment: By setting `optInput = null` in the first line, you're implying a default value, which means it's optional, but not supplying a default value for `num1`.

Comment: so they're both optional then?  how does this work...will try

Comment: Remove the `[Optional]` attribute and give it a default value... *or* add `[Optional]` to both params and remove the values.

Comment: i want it to be optional though - i made the changes..and now no error

public string UserAnswer([Optional] int num1, [Optional] int num2, string optInput = null)

Comment: related: [what-is-the-difference-between-optionalattribute-and-optional-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946919/what-is-the-difference-between-optionalattribute-and-optional-parameters-in-c-sh)

Comment: Its only optional if you do the `=`. I think you're misunderstanding what the Optional attribute actually does. The `=` makes it optional because you can choose not to provide a value. The Optional attribute doesn't work that way. You want what is being suggested to you.

Comment: @Josh: The `Optional` attribute *does* do that - but it's better to use the language integration. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/GAerL0 as an example of "yes, it really does introduce an optional parameter that the compiler can recognize when invoking the method".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `[Optional]` instead of the C# language integration for optional parameters. As far as the language is concerned (in terms of the method declaration part), `num1` is a required parameter, so it has to come before `optInput`. The compiler *does* know about `OptionalAttribute` when consuming methods, but not when declaring them.

Assuming you wanted both parameters to be optional, use the language integration for both:

```cs
public string UserAnswer(string optInput = null, int num1 = 0)
```

I would *strongly* advise against using `OptionalAttribute` explicitly - there's no reason to do so now there's language support, and it's more likely to cause confusion than to help when it comes to anyone else reading the code.

Comment: yeah but when i do this - it defaults my num1 and num2 to the value of 0 when i run my program which is overriding my user input.

Comment: i want the num1 and num2s to be optional in the sense that they can be used if a value is entered for them otherwise use the console.readline

Comment: @Jon Skeet good answer, I would like to add a little comment and useful information about the `[Optional]` attribute. By using this attribute explicitly, the compiler doesn't enforce the same strictness on type requirements; this itself can be bad.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: Given that I'm encouraging the OP not to use it at all, I don't think it's worth going into too much detail.

Comment: @JonSkeet Of course, just a little more details as to *why* not use it.

Comment: @testingTester: Then you should have put that in the question. You haven't shown where you're calling the method *at all*. I suggest you ask a new question for that part - because I don't think optional parameters will work for you there. The point of optional parameters is that the compiler works out whether to use the default values *at compile time*.

Comment: making them nullable does not work because they are being used in other methods where their values are stored for use in this method.  but I want that optional parameter on this method just so that i can make better unit tests out of this method.

Comment: @testingTester: Again, *ask a new question*. There's no point in adding more comments in *this* post, when those comments are irrelevant to what you've asked in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Any parameter in a function signature that has an assignment is an optional parameter. They don't need to have the optional attribute.

```
public string UserAnswer(string optInput = null, int num1 = 0)
```

In this example both optInput and num1 are optional. Going off your commment

> i want the num1 and num2s to be optional in the sense that they can be
>   used if a value is entered for them otherwise use the console.readline

We can't do exactly this. But we can change our parameters in a way that makes this easier. We can make the integer nullable

```
public string UserAnswer(string optInput = null, int? num1 = null)
```

Then this way we can use the value only when it isn't null. This is useful when any valid integer is considered a valid input and we need a way to determine if the argument was provided or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make your method header

```
public string UserAnswer(string optInput = null, int num1 = 0)
```

Comment: What is a `header` exactly?

Comment: In c++ land the `header` is a file that contains function declarations. I assume this is where he is coming from

Comment: @Josh I know what a `header` is :) I work with `c++` as well. My point is it's not tagged for `c++` nor is it called a header, thanks for the comments.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219274/what-is-the-difference-between-method-header-and-method-signature